# Several special IP connect to server with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, server, centos, cpanel

I want Several special IP connect to my server with ssh and block any another ip

what do you think about solve this question؟

i have centos 7

firewall is CSF

I use cpanel & whm

Comment: I'd say you generally block all access and only whitelist those "special IP" addresses as exceptions that may connect. That is obvious, so what is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let see the config file of SSH (server) **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

To limit all SSH users to access from specifics IP, just add at the bottom of the same file /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers *@192.168.0.*
```

It limit only to IPs like 192.168.0.*

If you have more networks, or just severals IPs, add those like this:

```
AllowUsers *@192.168.0.2  *@10.20.30.1 *@10.20.30.7
```

etc. And restart the PC or better, the service sshd

Answer (score 0):

You can setup limited IP access for the WHM and SSH with the  /etc/hosts.allow file. You can edit this file through command line OR WHM, For the WHM please try with WHM >>  Security Center >> Host Access Control

Here are the some information from cPanel documentations.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Host+Access+Control